# Change Password Plugin is not working in roundcube

Tags: webmail

I have installed roundcube manually in a cpanel based server. I have added and enabled Password Plugin. But while trying to change password after login i am getting the following error :

```
Could not save new password. Can't create socket connection to tcp://localhost:2222
```

I tried to change tcp:// to ssl:// and localhost to my domain host but none is working.